# The type 'int' does not support the operator '=='

Tags: f#

I want to calculate binom like this:

```
let t = seq { 1..10 } |> Seq.takeWhile (fun e -> e % 2 == 0)
```

but the compiler complain

```
playground.fsx(27,59): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not support the operator '=='
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

F# uses single `=` for equality operator:

```
let t = seq { 1..10 } |> Seq.takeWhile (fun e -> e % 2 = 0)
```